# Minecraft server constantly crashing

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, memory, java

I tried to make a VM instance on the Google cloud platform for my Minecraft server. But It's constantly crashing after a few hours. It says that I don't have enough memory but I think I allocated more then enough memory for a Minecraft server? I'm not very good at IT so I'm asking for your help please.

Last Error log:

```
 There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

 Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.

 Possible reasons:

   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
 Possible solutions:
   Reduce memory load on the system
   Increase physical memory or swap space
   Check if swap backing store is full
   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
   Decrease number of Java threads
   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
   JVM is running with Zero Based Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
     placed in the first 32GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 32GB virtual address.
 This output file may be truncated or incomplete.

  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2792), pid=13956, tid=0x00007f16405fa700

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_265-b01) (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0+deb9u1-b01)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.265-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f1675129000):  JavaThread "luckperms-scheduler-worker-189" daemon [_thread_new, id=11393, stack(0x00007f16404fa000,0x00007f16405fb000)]

Stack: [0x00007f16404fa000,0x00007f16405fb000],  sp=0x00007f16405f9b50,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xa7dce0]
V  [libjvm.so+0x4cd62c]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8c715c]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8be55e]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8c86e7]
V  [libjvm.so+0xa1e658]
V  [libjvm.so+0xa2273c]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8c47e2]
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x74a4]  start_thread+0xc4


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x00007f1675129000 JavaThread "luckperms-scheduler-worker-189" daemon [_thread_new, id=11393, stack(0x00007f16404fa000,0x00007f16405fb000)]
  0x00007f16750f3800 JavaThread "luckperms-scheduler-worker-188" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11386, stack(0x00007f16402f8000,0x00007f16403f9000)]
  0x00007f1675112800 JavaThread "luckperms-scheduler-worker-187" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11277, stack(0x00007f162aaf7000,0x00007f162abf8000)]
  0x00007f165c04b000 JavaThread "Netty Epoll Server IO #3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14245, stack(0x00007f162b7fc000,0x00007f162b8fd000)]
  0x00007f165c049000 JavaThread "Netty Epoll Server IO #2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14219, stack(0x00007f1630a97000,0x00007f1630b98000)]
```

** Hundreds of lines repeating similar to this:"0x00007f1648005800 JavaThread "pool-16-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=14087, stack(0x00007f162abf8000,0x00007f162acf9000)]" Will post them separately if needed.**

```
Other Threads:
  0x00007f168c0fb000 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f1678edf000,0x00007f1678fdf000] [id=13960]
  0x00007f168c143800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f167863d000,0x00007f167873d000] [id=13967]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

heap address: 0x0000000674c00000, size: 5300 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x00000007c0000000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 114047K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 2% used [0x0000000751980000,0x0000000753d07e30,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb2d8000,0x00000007bb380000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3570743K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074eb0dcb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120760K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00007f167b572000,0x00007f167bfcd000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f16781cc000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x00007f1691d5b720
 Begin Bits: [0x00007f1661a60000, 0x00007f1666d30000)
 End Bits:   [0x00007f1666d30000, 0x00007f166c000000)

Polling page: 0x00007f1692b83000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=88580Kb max_used=88596Kb free=157179Kb
 bounds [0x00007f167c38d000, 0x00007f1681abd000, 0x00007f168b38d000]
 total_blobs=26739 nmethods=25596 adapters=1048
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 31834.721 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 43872       3       java.net.SocketAddress::<init> (5 bytes)
Event: 31834.748 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 nmethod 43872 0x00007f167cb762d0 code [0x00007f167cb76440, 0x00007f167cb765f0]
Event: 31834.763 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 43873       3       java.io.PrintStream::<init> (19 bytes)
Event: 31834.764 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 nmethod 43873 0x00007f167e6e6d10 code [0x00007f167e6e6f20, 0x00007f167e6e7698]
Event: 31834.764 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 43874   !   3       java.io.PrintStream::toCharset (22 bytes)
Event: 31834.765 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 nmethod 43874 0x00007f167f423dd0 code [0x00007f167f423fa0, 0x00007f167f4244d8]
Event: 31834.765 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 43875       3       java.io.PrintStream::<init> (49 bytes)
Event: 31834.767 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 nmethod 43875 0x00007f1681ab4810 code [0x00007f1681ab4a40, 0x00007f1681ab55a8]
Event: 32134.765 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 43876       1       org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.entity.CraftMinecartChest::getType (4 bytes)
Event: 32134.790 Thread 0x00007f168c13e000 nmethod 43876 0x00007f167eef9250 code [0x00007f167eef93a0, 0x00007f167eef94b0]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 31696.080 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=561 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 1729856K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 100% used [0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bff50000,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb380000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3544911K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 97% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074d1d3cb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120759K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 31696.243 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=561 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 77568K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 0% used [0x0000000751980000,0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb2c0000,0x00000007bb380000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3550127K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074d6ebcb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120759K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 31812.264 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=562 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 1729792K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 100% used [0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb2c0000,0x00000007bb380000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3550127K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074d6ebcb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120759K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 31812.434 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=562 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 77568K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 0% used [0x0000000751980000,0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bff40000,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb380000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3555295K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074dbf7cb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120759K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 31924.821 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=563 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 1729792K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 100% used [0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bff40000,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb380000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3555295K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074dbf7cb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120760K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 31924.991 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=563 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 77696K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 0% used [0x0000000751980000,0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb2e0240,0x00000007bb380000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3560415K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074e0f7cb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120760K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 32041.334 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=564 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 1729920K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 100% used [0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb2e0240,0x00000007bb380000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3560415K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074e0f7cb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120760K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 32041.508 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=564 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 77632K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 0% used [0x0000000751980000,0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bff50000,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb380000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3565551K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074e5fbcb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120760K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 32155.312 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=565 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 1729856K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 100% used [0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bff50000,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb380000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3565551K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074e5fbcb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120760K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 32155.507 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=565 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 1730560K, used 77664K [0x0000000751980000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 1652224K, 0% used [0x0000000751980000,0x0000000751980000,0x00000007b6700000)
  from space 78336K, 99% used [0x00000007b6700000,0x00000007bb2d8000,0x00000007bb380000)
  to   space 78336K, 0% used [0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007bb380000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 3618304K, used 3570743K [0x0000000674c00000, 0x0000000751980000, 0x0000000751980000)
  object space 3618304K, 98% used [0x0000000674c00000,0x000000074eb0dcb0,0x0000000751980000)
 Metaspace       used 120760K, capacity 137598K, committed 137804K, reserved 1167360K
  class space    used 16786K, capacity 20269K, committed 20352K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 20740.958 Thread 0x00007f168ce52800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1680ade2e4 method=net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.CriterionConditionEntity$b.a(Lnet/minecraft/server/v1_16_R2/LootTableInfo;)Z @ 5
Event: 20740.965 Thread 0x00007f168ce52800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f1680a6fa84 method=net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.EntityWolf.tick()V @ 23
Event: 20741.807 Thread 0x00007f168ce52800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f1680ade2e4 method=net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.CriterionConditionEntity$b.a(Lnet/minecraft/server/v1_16_R2/LootTableInfo;)Z @ 5
Event: 20882.721 Thread 0x00007f168ce52800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f1681697afc method=net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.AxisAlignedBB.e(DDD)Z @ 24
Event: 20882.721 Thread 0x00007f168ce52800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f16816e6614 method=net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.AxisAlignedBB.e(DDD)Z @ 24
Event: 20909.826 Thread 0x00007f168ce52800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f16803be3dc method=com.sekwah.advancedportals.bukkit.listeners.Listeners.onDamEvent(Lorg/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDamageEvent;)V @ 37
Event: 20964.782 Thread 0x00007f168ce52800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f16803c48a4 method=net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.EntityMinecartAbstract.collide(Lnet/minecraft/server/v1_16_R2/Entity;)V @ 40
Event: 21000.110 Thread 0x00007f168d837800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f167f424360 method=java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.offer(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 72
Event: 23333.914 Thread 0x00007f168ce52800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00007f167fe5083c method=net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.EntityVillagerTrader.eY()V @ 25
Event: 23434.717 Thread 0x00007f168ce52800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f167e1bc700 method=java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V @ 145

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 32135.671 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5e70128) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 32135.673 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5e759d0) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 32135.676 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5e84ff8) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 32135.678 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5e8b950) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 32135.680 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5e922f8) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 32135.717 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5e97978) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 32135.719 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5e9d2d0) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 32135.721 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5ea2fc0) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 32135.768 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5ea9008) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 32135.770 Thread 0x000055c95f3c5000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/UnixException'> (0x00000007a5eaeae8) thrown at [/build/openjdk-8-lU31QX/openjdk-8-8u265-b01/src/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 711]

Events (10 events):
Event: 32041.325 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 32041.510 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 32041.516 Thread 0x00007f1675112800 Thread added: 0x00007f1675112800
Event: 32101.525 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 32101.534 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 32101.534 Thread 0x00007f16750f3800 Thread exited: 0x00007f16750f3800
Event: 32146.505 Thread 0x00007f16750f3800 Thread added: 0x00007f16750f3800
Event: 32155.306 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 32155.514 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 32155.521 Thread 0x00007f1675129000 Thread added: 0x00007f1675129000


Dynamic libraries:
674c00000-7c13e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7c13e0000-800000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
55c95c030000-55c95c031000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 662460                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
55c95c230000-55c95c231000 r--p 00000000 08:01 662460                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
55c95c231000-55c95c232000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 662460                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
55c95e09a000-55c95f48c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f1624000000-7f16265d7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

**Thousands lines of 7f162981e000-7f16298de000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 **
(I had to delete them because It couldn't fit here I will post them separately if they are important.)

```
7f169295d000-7f1692961000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1692961000-7f1692984000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 524356                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7f1692984000-7f1692985000 r--s 00001000 08:01 655423                     /home/minecraft/BOBVALIKJEDE/datapacks/2.zip
7f1692985000-7f1692988000 r--s 0000f000 08:01 662522                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar
7f1692988000-7f169298a000 r--s 00001000 08:01 662521                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
7f169298a000-7f169298b000 r--s 00010000 08:01 662529                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
7f169298b000-7f169298c000 r--s 0000a000 08:01 662523                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
7f169298c000-7f1692992000 r--s 0003d000 08:01 662527                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
7f1692992000-7f16929ad000 r--s 00394000 08:01 662520                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
7f16929ad000-7f1692a08000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1692a08000-7f1692a70000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1692a70000-7f1692a78000 rw-s 00000000 08:01 1048622                    /tmp/hsperfdata_root/13956
7f1692a78000-7f1692a79000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1692a79000-7f1692a7c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1692a7c000-7f1692b7d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1692b7d000-7f1692b81000 r--s 0003a000 08:01 662528                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
7f1692b81000-7f1692b82000 r--s 0000d000 08:01 662526                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
7f1692b84000-7f1692b85000 r--p 00023000 08:01 524356                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7f1692b85000-7f1692b86000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 524356                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7f1692b86000-7f1692b87000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffcc90b8000-7ffcc90d9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffcc91ce000-7ffcc91d0000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffcc91d0000-7ffcc91d2000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx5300M -Xms5300M 
java_command: paper-204.jar
java_class_path (initial): paper-204.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
USERNAME=root
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xa7e790], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xa7e790], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x8c2660], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x8c2660], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x8c2660], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x8c2660], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x8c2510], sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x8c2b80], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x8c2b80], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x8c2b80], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x8c2b80], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

uname:Linux 4.9.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.228-1 (2020-07-05) x86_64
libc:glibc 2.24 NPTL 2.24 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 23800, NOFILE 1048576, AS infinity
load average:0.24 0.21 0.18

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        6115244 kB
MemFree:          113056 kB
MemAvailable:          0 kB
Buffers:             652 kB
Cached:            67572 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          5860044 kB
Inactive:          65516 kB
Active(anon):    5857608 kB
Inactive(anon):    62880 kB
Active(file):       2436 kB
Inactive(file):     2636 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                88 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       5857424 kB
Mapped:            10132 kB
Shmem:             63064 kB
Slab:              22556 kB
SReclaimable:       9584 kB
SUnreclaim:        12972 kB
KernelStack:        2576 kB
PageTables:        14336 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3057620 kB
Committed_AS:    6289780 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      104436 kB
DirectMap2M:     6187008 kB
DirectMap1G:     2097152 kB

container (cgroup) information:
container_type: cgroupv1
cpu_cpuset_cpus: 0-1
cpu_memory_nodes: 0
active_processor_count: 2
cpu_quota: -1
cpu_period: 100000
cpu_shares: -1
memory_limit_in_bytes: -1
memory_and_swap_limit_in_bytes: -2
memory_soft_limit_in_bytes: -1
memory_usage_in_bytes: 6068023296
memory_max_usage_in_bytes: 0


CPU:total 2 (initial active 2) (1 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 79 stepping 0, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x1
cpu MHz     : 2200.000
cache size  : 56320 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp kaiser fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat md_clear arch_capabilities
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs taa
bogomips    : 4400.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x1
cpu MHz     : 2200.000
cache size  : 56320 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp kaiser fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat md_clear arch_capabilities
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs taa
bogomips    : 4400.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 6115244k(112932k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.265-b01) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0+deb9u1-b01), built on Aug 12 2020 08:17:29 by "buildd" with gcc 6.3.0 20170516

time: Sun Sep 27 01:45:57 2020
timezone: UTC
elapsed time: 32155 seconds (0d 8h 55m 55s)
```

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server/Requirements

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough memory. Your server has 5972MB of available memory, of which 5800M you allocated for the memory allocation pool in the JVM. This means that the rest of the operating system, and the JVM itself shares 172MB memory total, which is way too low.

So the problem is not the amount of memory you gave to the Java process, the problem is that you tried to give more than you have. You should increase the memory of the VM instance.

As for how much memory is enough: I don't know anything about the minecraft server, so 5.8G might be enough for that. For the rest of the system, it is easy to guess. Stop the minecraft server, and run the `free` command. The "Used" column in the "Mem" row will tell you how much memory the system currently use. Add about 50M to this (an empty JVM gulps up 30-40 megs of memory), and this is the bare minimum you'll need for your system to run.

If is better to give more memory, however, as Linux will use the excess memory as filesystem cache, which might come in handy if the Minecraft process use the filesystem often.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that I have enough memory for the Minecraft server process itself but I don't have enough memory for the rest (operating system etc.) ? If so is this "-Xmx5300M -Xms5300M" how much memory I allocated to the java process ? And how much memory should I allocate to the rest?

Comment: I've updated my answer.